# Why is a macro necessary for assigning a symbol's value?

Tags: common-lisp

If I have

```
(defun nil! (v)
  (setf v nil))

(defmacro nil!! (v)
  `(setf ,v nil))
```

Both the function and the macro look like they should set the input value to nil. However, only the macro actually sets the input variable to nil. Why can't the function do this as well?

Comment: That explained it, thanks.